# How do we handle tags that have more than one meaning

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki, tag-synonyms

A tag "vein" has been established in connection with a question dealing with a model called VEIN. A vein is of course also a common term in geology. So in this case a vein tag has two meanings. How should this be handled?

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday I rejected the creation of the vein tag for two reasons: my experience with veins relating to Earth Science is geology veins and secondly because I didn't have the context of the proposal.

Having read the context of the proposed vein tag - for vehicle emissions relating to the R Package - after I rejected the tag there was not much I could do. I couldn't retract the rejection & suggest an alternative.

My idea is to have two vein tags, one vein-geology and the other vein-r-package.