# Removal of tags

Tags: support, tags

Regarding the question, *[How do we handle tags that have more than one meaning](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1877/how-do-we-handle-tags-that-have-more-than-one-meaning)*, I have added the tags `vein-geology`and `vein-r-package`.

The documentation for the `vein` tag was copied to the `vein-r-package` tag. How does the old `vein` tag get removed so it is no longer a tag that can be selected?

Comment: Noticed questions using tags like a rock for Identifying rocks, though that has been banned.

Answer (score 2):

It will be automatically removed today 03:00 UTC

> [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or “zombie”) tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags)
>
> You should edit out the tag from all the questions that use it. Note that you should probably seek consensus on the per-site meta before doing so, if the tag was somehow added to a significant number of questions without anyone noticing the misspelling.
>
> Tags not associated with any question are automatically destroyed at 03:00 UTC every day.
>
> Tags which are misspelled should have the questions under them retagged to the appropriate tag, which will result in the misspelled tag's destruction due to having no uses.